# Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to to select a field from Data table `dt_branches_global` in such a way that, if `radioButton_QP` is Checked then the Data table will contain a `string` field otherwise the Data Table contain an `int` field. This is what I am doing. But I am getting error while initializing the variable Var.

```
var AllBranch_IDs = null;

if (radioButton_QP.Checked == true)   
AllBranch_IDs = dt_branches_global.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("BusinessSectorID")).ToArray();
else

AllBranch_IDs = dt_branches_global.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("BusinessSectorID")).ToArray();
```

Comment: That is because the type if `var` needs to be inferred by the compiler at compile time, `null` alone cannot yield an inferred type. Either don't use `var` or include a cast on the null: `var AllBranch_IDs = (string[])null;` - either results in telling the compiler what the type is. Though it seems you are then going to run into the issue that one result is a `string[]` and the other appears to be an `int[]`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler is still strongly typed so it needs to figure out the type. It is impossible for the compiler to infer the type of you assign it to null. Then you later on try to assign it to two different types. An array of ints and an array of strings.

Try something like:

```
string[] AllBranch_IDs = null;

if (radioButton_QP.Checked == true)   
AllBranch_IDs = dt_branches_global.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("BusinessSectorID")).ToArray();
else

AllBranch_IDs = dt_branches_global.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>("BusinessSectorID").ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 for guessing it's for display purposes and converting from int to string

Answer (score 6):

As it stands, the type cannot be inferred from `null` - `null` could be any reference type.

i.e. The problem here

```
var AllBranch_IDs = null;
```

is that the compiler would need to scan to the following lines of code to deduce the type of `AllBranch_IDs` (which isn't possible in C# anyway), and wouldn't work due to the dynamic nature of the type - you assign it either `IEnumerable<string>` or `IEnumerable<int>`).

You could use `IEnumerable<object>` and then box the ints:

e.g.:

```
     IEnumerable<object> AllBranch_IDs = null;

     if (new Random().Next(10) > 5)
     {
        AllBranch_IDs = new [] {1,2,3,4}.Cast<object>().ToArray();
     }
     else
     {
        AllBranch_IDs = new [] {"hello", "world"}.ToArray();
     }
```

Declaring it as `dynamic` would also compile, viz `dynamic AllBranch_IDs = null`, although the consumer of the result would need to be aware that the type is dynamic.