# Cannot assign null to an implicitly-typed variable

Tags: c#

According to Visual Studio this is not ok:

```
var foo = null;
```

But this is ok:

```
var foo = false ? (double?)null : null;
```

Why? Is the `(double?)null` affecting also the `null` in the else branch?

Comment: Because the second expression clearly has type `double?`.

Comment: But it evaluates to null? What makes the `: null` a double?

Comment: Related post - [Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24449510/465053)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implicitly typed variable declaration/assignment serves two purposes:

- Decides the value of the variable, and
- Decides the type of the variable.

Your first declaration has `null` for the value, with no way to figure out the type (it could be anything derived from `System.Object`, or a `Nullable<T>`). That is why it is an error.

Your second declaration pinpoints the type as `Nullable<double>` because of the cast. That is why C# allows it.

It goes without saying that `double? foo = null` would be much easier to read.

Comment: But why is the `null` in the else branch also casted to double?

Comment: @user2061057 Because conditional expression requires both branches to have compatible types, and `null` is compatible with `double?` type.

Answer (score 7):

Because compiler cannot predict the type of null. Null can be assigned to any nullable datatype also to any reference type variable. So for implicit conversion, you have to cast null to some specific type.

```
var dt = (DateTime?)null; // This is correct
var dt1 = null; // This will throw compile time error.
```

Answer (score 2):

The second example has `double?` type and the compiler knows it. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables)

> It is important to understand that the var keyword does not mean
>   "variant" and does not indicate that the variable is loosely typed, or
>   late-bound. It just means that the compiler determines and assigns the
>   most appropriate type.

The compiler should ensure the type match with `var`.

```
var foo = null;
```

The compiler can't identify the type of foo.

```
var foo = false ? (double?)null : null;
```

Now the `foo` has `double?` type.

Comment: Ok. But I fail to understand what makes the `: null` a double? It is possible to write e.g. `var foo = false ? (double?)null : (int?)null;`

Comment: @user2061057 Both branches of the ternary operator _should_ be the same type. Try this code: `var wat = true ? 1 : "Hello World";`
You will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning null to a `var` to a value, VS can't identify  what type gonna be (double,int,bool etc). Var is commonly used when you don't know what type your value gonna be.

Your second declaration pinpoints the type as Nullable that's why you don't get an exception/error.